# Testing a condition to replace elements of amatrix

Tags: matrix, replacement

I want to write a code that checks each element of a given matrix `C2` and in case they are't 0 or 1 , replaces them with 1. My code is so far as follows and the code should does the following for any $n\times n$ matrices. Any ideas?

```
C2 = Table[RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}];
For[i = 2, i < 10, i++, C3 = MatrixPower[C2, i]; C2 = C3 + C2]
```

Comment: This question makes no sense. `C2` is generated by code which constrains its elements to either 0 or 1, so there no need look for elements that other values. Your For-loop doesn't have any relation to the question you ask and I see no reason for including it the question. Please clarify your question.

Comment: `Unitize[Abs[C2]]`

Comment: `Clip[C2, {0, 1}]`

Comment: The whole question is about setting values of 1 to none zero none 1 values after the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You can use a `Do` loop redefining the matrix `C2` as `Unitize[C2 + MatrixPower[C2, i]]` at step `i`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
C2a = Table[RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}];

Do[C2a = Unitize[C2a + MatrixPower[C2a, i]], {i, 2, 10}]
```

Display using[`ArrayPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html) with matrix entries rendered using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
ArrayPlot[C2a, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red}, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1 -> 15, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 8, Black], #2 - .5] &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose@C2, {2}]]
```

[image]

**2.** You can also use [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) to recursively modify `C2`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
C2b = Table[RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}];

C2b = Fold[Unitize[# + MatrixPower[#, #2]] &, C2b, Range[2, 10]];

ArrayPlot[C2b, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red}, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1 -> 15, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 8, Black], #2 - .5] &, 
   Reverse /@ Transpose @ C2b, {2}]]
```

[image]

**Note:** Both methods produce the same matrix as `Unitize[C2]` where `C2` is the matrix produced by your code (and both are much faster than the `For` loop):

```
SeedRandom[1]
C2 = Table[RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}];

For[i = 2, i < 10, i++, C3 = MatrixPower[C2, i]; C2 = C3 + C2]

C2unitized = Unitize[C2];

C2a == C2b == C2unitized
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but I think there is a misunderstanding in regards to my question. Clearly the C2 which is created at the beginning has only elements of 0 and 1. It is after the for loop which the matrix get none zero or one values and I like all the these none zero or one values to become 1.

Comment: @Nikray, `Unitize[mat]` makes all non-zero values of input matrix `mat` 1.  When the initial matrix is a 0-1 matrix, using `Unitize` at each step of the Do loop gives the same final matrix as you would get from using `Unitize` on the final matrix produced by a Do loop which sets `C2 = C2 +MatrixPower[C2,i]` at step i. You can see this ...

Comment: using  `SeedRandom[1]; C2a = Table[RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}]; Do[C2a = C2 + MatrixPower[C2, i], {i, 2, 10}]; C2a = Unitize[C2a];
SeedRandom[1]; C2b = Table[ RandomChoice[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 30], {j, 1, 30}]; Do[C2b = Unitize[C2 + MatrixPower[C2, i]], {i, 2, 10}]; C2b == C2a`